Why doesn't text read line height from style?
I have simple compose function:
@Preview
@Composable
fun Test(){

    val typography = Typography(
        labelSmall = TextStyle(
            color = Color.Blue,
            lineHeight = TextUnit(200f, TextUnitType.Sp),
            letterSpacing = TextUnit(10f, TextUnitType.Sp)
        )
    )

    MaterialTheme(typography = typography){
        Box(modifier = Modifier.size(500.dp), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
            Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally){
                Text(
                    text = "hello",
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.labelSmall
                )
            }
        }
    }

}

I expect to see blue hello with spacing between letters and spacing above and below the text. But i see a different result:

As you can seen there is no spacing above and below the text for some reason. But if i specify lineHeight parameter instead of style with the value from the same style, i will get the correct line height:
@Preview
@Composable
fun Test(){

    val typography = Typography(
        labelSmall = TextStyle(
            color = Color.Blue,
            lineHeight = TextUnit(200f, TextUnitType.Sp),
            letterSpacing = TextUnit(10f, TextUnitType.Sp)
        )
    )

    MaterialTheme(typography = typography){
        Box(modifier = Modifier.size(500.dp), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
            Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally){
                Text(
                    text = "hello",
                    lineHeight = MaterialTheme.typography.labelSmall.lineHeight
                )
            }
        }
    }

}


Why doesn't text read line height from style ?
